# How to run a GWT web application using my local machine name or domain name instead of local IP(127.0.0.1)/localhost?

Tags: gwt

I am very new to GWT and I am running my GWT web application through my eclipse Europa(GWT Hosted mode) using my Local IP address or localhost and 8888 port in the URL.
like the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/login.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

OR

```
http://localhost:8888/login.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

Now when I am trying to run the very same application by replacing the above localhost/IP address with my local 
machine name(for example: sandip.com. "sandip.com" is my Full computer name) 
like: `http://sandip.com:8888/login.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`
it is showing below message, hence not working.

---

Host Not Found

DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist) or Server did not accept the connection.

Please check that the host name has been spelled correctly.

---

But I have tried doing this for my other non-GWT based web application and it has worked properly.
Shall I need to do any changes? Please suggest.

and also I want to change this default port(i.e. 8888) to some other ex: 8773 and want to use https instead of http.

The above requirment is possible if I separately deploy in my local Tomcat and in this case if I have to change any code in eclipse, I need to redeploy
in Tomcat for testing. Is there any way to achieve this through Eclipse(i.e. GWT Hosted mode)?

Comment: HELP!!! Can someone answer atleast one of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619651/how-to-send-data-to-port-of-gwt-web-application-project-when-debugging ?????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619651/how-to-send-data-to-port-of-gwt-web-application-project-when-debugging

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm quite sure you won't be able to run your GWT application in hosted mode on HTTPS! That will have to wait until you've actually built and deployed it on your sandip.com webserver...

Then,

- use `-port 9876` to have hosted mode run on a different port.
- use `-bindAddress 0.0.0.0` (or another non-localhost IP) to make your app available on other machines beside localhost.

As for the DNS error, does `sandip.com` resolve internally on your network?

The whole point of using hosted mode is for ease of development. You should never ever expose your hosted mode app to the world, you do understand that right?

Cheers,

Comment: +1 But FYI: It is possible to use development mode with HTTPS. Just deploy to an HTTPS-enabled web server, then run DevMode locally and use a URL combination like `https://www.example.com?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` (the web server can also be e.g. a Tomcat on your local machine `https://127.0.0.1:8443?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`)

Comment: OK thanks, but then it is really not DevMode that's handling HTTPS, but the webserver, isn't it? My point is that a lot of other stuff can go wrong when developing GWT apps; no need to complicate with arcane webserver setup...

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/README-SSL.txt