# How to send data to port of gwt web application project when debugging?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, web-applications, ip

I am new in gwt web application projects.

After debugging a gwt web application project on eclipse, I got a url in this format -

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8888/macar.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997.
```

I debugged it on a home pc and my ip address is not public.

1. What will be the server address? The url above?
2. what is going to be the port number?
3. How do I ascertain that the data I am sending (gps data) gets to server via port?
4. Must I have a public ip address to do the above? if yes, how do I make my home ip address public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is  `http://127.0.0.1` :the amazing localhost

The port is `8888`

The Rest is the same : `gwt.codesvr` is an parameter(extra data) `127.0.0.1` again the amazing localhost : `9997` is the port where `GWT` is converted to `JavaScripts` (Supported by `GWT` plugin on Browser)

When you send data from two different location in web application you mean from server that the application deployed at to a client or user(or Vice Versa) ,so all you have to do is to launch your application in Public (Online) and by logic of your Application you can control data flow between server to your users

Your Question here is more about dealing with services so you have to provide a service give an interface on client side connect it to a `RPC call to server` and run code on server side now you've created a Client-Server(Browser-Server) link you can more about `RPC` call [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC)

Comment: thanks for the input. you clarified the parameters in the link. Actually i am trying to send gps data from client to server. the data is suppose to appear in the url above. but it is not :( Guess the problem is that web server and database are not using same databse. database is H2. do you know how i can configure them to use same database?

Comment: So try to search how to configure your web server what ever it's to deal with database whatever

Answer (score 0):

GWT with Eclipse runs an embedded local web server on your local code.  You don't have to worry about it, the url you mentioned should work.  You can easily modify ports when you add new modules.  If you have all necessary data locally to test then you should be set to test the client, server, and client-server functions.

However at some point, you may need to interact with server-side data located remotely -- e.g., debug local code against production data.  One way to go about it is to configure the url's for each server you may need to interact with as a function of a single "server" configuration entry point -- e.g., an Enum variable holding the active server of interest.  The urls for each server could possibly be configured in property file(s).  Your server code needs to rely on an interface returning the configured url's you need as fonction of the active server configuration.  Then you are set to easily switch to any server data of interest.  I hope it is clear and on topic.